# How do you synchronize a fork with parent project if it is big?

Tags: git, architecture, open-source, project

This is a theoretical question, I just want to make it clear for myself.

Let's say you get a task from your customer to make something big. Let it be a custom browser with bells and whistles or a custom Android ROM with a lot of customer services.

After some research you find out that you can use some opensource project as a basement but the customer's wishlist requires you to make lots of changes that include adding or deleting a lot of code, removing some modules from the project, changing the architecture of some components, rewriting something deep in the heart of the project etc.

Now let's say you have successfully implemented everything, the customer gave you the money and made an offer to sync the code base with current parent project's state for some extra payment.

And now the question: what is the best way to sync the code base with the parent if:

1. You are using some version controlling system (i'm personally interested in git but if there're solutions for other ones, I'd like to know)
2. Your development was lasting for some years while the parent project didn't stand still and you didn't fetch changes from it because there wasn't a line about this in the contract.
3. You couldn't know anything about supporting the project in the future
4. You made so many changes that simple `git merge` would produce a lot of conflicts and resolving them is similar to rewriting everything from scratch
5. You're not willing to spend the whole life transferring the changes.

If there's no way for quick merging, what is the best approach in terms of architecture to avoid these situations?

Comment: This is really specific for a theoretical question... 

Comment: Point 2 is the main blocker of quick merge. Try to negotiate to include fetching changes into the contract before the project starts.

Comment: "There's no right way to do wrong."  If you've forked the project and worked for years without paying attention to it, what you have is no longer a fork in any useful sense of the word.  Don't get into this situation.

Comment: It is clear for me that some problems can be reduced by specifying some conditions in the contract before the work has begun. I want to understand how big companies do this. In Russia this is Yandex with Yandex.Browser, in China - Xiaomi, Huawei, etc, in Korea - Samsung. All these companies really make a fork of opensource (Chromium, Android), implement their features and then support it somehow to not rewrite everything everytime the new version appears. How do they? How should the architecture be made to support the later changes?

Comment: What open source project did you use?

Comment: This question is not about any specific project. It is about a method of making things right whatever project it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is actually probably your best bet.  It has lots of great merge tools.  If the original project is a git fork, then you are good, create a new branch from the current code-base, then either merge your changes in, or do a rebase.  It will be slow, painful, and will probably need to go one-commit-at-a-time.  Hopefully you wrote lots of unit tests to find your failures.  Learn [git-bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect), it will save your life (determining when things broke in your commit stream).

In response to your comment, big projects that fork other big projects:

(1) try REALLY HARD to keep their changes modularized and out of the core functions of the parent application

(2) go through this same process of merging or rebasing on a regular basis.

Regardless, from a logical standpoint, you will have to resolve all the conflicts, and it will likely be expensive and time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally when you use an open source project as a base you should chose one with excellent extension mechanisms and keep up to date with it. It sounds like this project has reached the point it which merging might be very difficult. Apart from going through merge hell another option is to start a new project using git for source control, an appropriate build tool for the language and a dependency on the open source project. Once you have this set up slowly add the existing functionality you built out but this time in an extensible manner with you still being able to reuse your old code. Write lots of unit tests as you go and frequently update the version of the open source project.

If you are going to attempted merge hell I'd suggest attempting to pull down changes from the open source project in stages, instead of getting the latest start with a build that wasn't that far away from what you used as a base and incrementally update from there fixing breaking changes as you go. Depending on your skill level this could be more work and still leaves you in the position of having  project with dependencies not set up correctly.